# Does async response from server creates a new thread itself

Tags: c#, .net

In .net async response's is it self a thread or it is on the main UI thread? And again, if its not a different thread does it all get to a blocking state if I am working in the async response method?

Comment: It would be good if you can limit question to one programming language.

Comment: I went ahead and removed [tag:Java] because 2 of the 3 tags were not Java related.

Comment: Is this winform/ASP/WPF/Silverlight/console/other?  Additionally, please provide details about the type of call.  It will vary dramatically based on the implementation.  It could create it's own thread, it could be another threadpool thread, it could be the thread that first fired the async operation, it could be some other thread (i.e. the UI or main thread), or possibly even something else.  You'll need to provide a lot more information to really get an answer.  (Or you could just run the program and look at the thread IDs.)

Comment: Ohh sorry for the confusion I created.
I am asking about a desktop application only for .net c# :)

Comment: If you provide more detail on *what*  SDK, someone might be able to give you a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET it might. Sometimes it will, and other times it won't.

See this for more insight: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/fa9e1830-ef06-4dd1-8ef7-59ebf04ab1e6/

Comment: Beauty but long one, kinda complex to understand.
What I got from that blog or convo is that async is working under thread pool so you dont need to create threads.
correct me if I am wrong.